# Customize Circular & Scrollable layout / Gallery / ViewPager

Tags: android

I am trying to make customize Gallery/ViewPager which has nodes placed in circular position.

I [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4403121/582571). which is helpful and [i am able to make customize gallery like this](http://s23.postimg.org/3tyyvs40r/device_2013_07_22_152349_2.png)

Problem in this approach is that, space between two nodes is not equal, plus node did not rotate according to angle

[I want to make like this](http://s15.postimg.org/n5ja52fxn/scrollable_circular_gallery23.png)