# launching app by swiping on screen(like Switchr app)

Tags: android

I have a news app.It is  supposed to launch by swiping on the screen(homescreen or while in any other activity like switchr app).I learned to code swiping patterns but in my case I have to do exactly in the following way(swiping bottom right to top left)..Kindly have a look over following pictorial representation

1.Firstly app should launch  by swiping bottom right to top left on the screen

2.next,show the user with list of scrollable arc menu buttons embedded in it like second image

3.when a user clicks on particular button it has to show a brief description about the content like third image

my problems:

creating arc like scrollable menu on bottom right side of the screen(I googled sia ahmed's solution over here ,it helped me a bit)

creating that parachute like structure(image 3) when user clicks particular bubble like button in arc menu..

please guide me
[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the menu check out [arcmenu](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu) by daCapricorn on github. Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732739/possibility-of-a-curved-gallery).

The balloon bit is trickier. I know of a [balloon hint](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/PinyinIME/+/froyo/src/com/android/inputmethod/pinyin/BalloonHint.java) code for android but i haven't seen it in action.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for your help mam ..I am learning balloon hint mam  will update my status